# Push to gist while having non-code files

Tags: git, gist

I cloned a public gist and made some changes. Now I have a new code, plus several files in the same folder that running the code generates.

I want to push the code on my computer up to my gist -- is it possible to do so with non-code files in the same git folder? I tried and encountered some fatal error

`fatal: the remote hung up unexpectedly`

`fatal: recursion detected in die handler`

Comment: It doesn't matter whether your files contain code or text or anything else. Have you added and commited them locally? Useful link on adding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572549/difference-of-git-add-a-and-git-add

Comment: Yes, git status shows clean working directory, and that my branch is ahead of origin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that server is down or a corrupt repository. Then you could try :

```
git fsck
```

Also this answer might be useful: [git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240815/git-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

Comment: I really suspected that the reason is because I tried to push some pictures into `gist.github.com`. I tried to push another folder with only codes to gist and it worked fine. Are you sure I can push non-code files to gist?

Comment: sure, this is very similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425770/how-do-you-upload-images-to-a-gist

Comment: I just put a random image in the folder that works fine, and that recreates the problem. I guess it's possible to put an image up gist, just not via direct push.

Answer (score 0):

We had a proxy issue that caused the "fatal: recursion detected in die handler".  When I connected to our git server directly without the proxy, this issue went away.