# Can images on 'user-images.githubusercontent.com' be deleted?

Tags: image, github, github-api

I accidentally uploaded an image I don't want to have on GitHub. I had thought that I had cut private information from an image I was uploading for example purposes, but the private information remains. It contains things like a hostname that I would prefer is not public knowledge.

Is there a way to remove that image from github's image registry?

I know it's highly unlikely that someone ever unearths it by checking all the possible destinations for the image on their server, but it would give me peace of mind.

Comment: Still waiting on a response from GitHub and if they fix the problem I will accept your answer

Comment: Have you gotten a response? I'm kinda curious myself.

Comment: @jhpratt They finally got back to me. Took a while. Accepting your answer

Comment: what about just listing all images I uploaded/pasted? I think some of them are no more used, so I could delete them... but how to find them?

Comment: unsure the answer to that unfortunately

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Whatever the private info was, invalidate it if possible.
2. [Contact GitHub](https://github.com/contact). They normally respond quite quickly (I've frequently received responses in just a few hours), as they're obviously the ones that have the ability to remove it.

Comment: Using [this search](https://support.github.com/?tags=dotcom-direct&q=delete+images) from the link above will show the GitHub virtual assistant at the top of the list. Clicking on that allows you to just paste in a particular image/video link which you would like to remove, and it will automatically create a ticket for you.

Comment: @warrenwiser I had to search for "delete images from githubusercontent" for the virtual assistant to appear. Thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: @Brecht thank you for the update; the link seems to work for me less than half the times I try. weird! for anyone else facing this error, click the link in the second bullet of the answer and search "delete images".